# How can I insert text into every 5th line?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I want to add keywords to every 5th line in my file.

### Source File

```
45657m
5535d
46477s
6445d
5656f
5466h
45345f
54777h
...
```

### Desired Output

```
45657m
5535d
46477s
6445d
keyword
5656f
5466h
45345f
54777h
keyword
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use GNU Awk, Modulo Number of Records

Just insert your text after every 4th line, like so:

```
$ awk '{print}; NR % 4 == 0 {print "keyword"}' /tmp/corpus 
45657m
5535d
46477s
6445d
keyword
5656f
5466h
45345f
54777h
keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1~4i\keyword' file
```

Answer (score 0):

### A GNU Sed Solution

The sed solution uses a series of (N)ext commands, followed by an (a)ppend to insert the keyword itself. For example:

```
$ sed 'N; N; N; a\keyword' /tmp/corpus 
45657m
5535d
46477s
6445d
keyword
5656f
5466h
45345f
54777h
keyword
```

Because the number of (N)ext commands must be specified manually, it might be unwieldy for larger intervals. In such cases, [my awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580320/1301972) would be easier to modify.